# Prestashop 1.7 Addresses

Tags: prestashop, rename, checkout, prestashop-1.7

I want to rename labels in the address section. For example rename: Company, State, Phone.
The addresses section after personal information,  when a user is not registered.
Can not find where, how can I do that? Help, please.
Thanks.

[addresses image.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baK4W.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Filename to edit is: 
/public_html/classes/form/CustomerAddressFormatter.php